# ruby on rails 4.2 repository on www.softwarecollections.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, repository

We have a fully implemented Katello 3.0 running on our environment. While trying to upgrade to Katello 3.2, I have been noticed that the ruby on rail 4.2 repository on www.softwarecollections.org has nothing and seems the collections are redirected to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/.

We do have a very tight firewall setup and we allowed www.softwarecollections.org to whitelist earlier. whitelisting any new url is time consuming and goes through various approval badly.

Is there any plan to host collections to existing location at https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/rhscl/rh-ror42/ so I can plan accordingly.

Thanks in advance
Sam